# RecyclerView is scrolling to up automatically and flickering

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-recyclerview

Basically I'm using a `RecyclerView` with `gridAdapter` to load images from server. But the problem is items of `RecyclerView` are blinking in a quirky manner. I've tried all the possible solutions but none of them worked so far.

I tried to update `glide` version from `4.4.0` to `4.8.0` but it's futile. I also tried to disable the animations of `RecyclerView` but that couldn't help. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

[image: See how Images are blinking]

Code:

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(v.getContext(),3);
gridLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
gridLayoutManager.setItemPrefetchEnabled(true);
gridLayoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(20);

posts_rView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
posts_rView.setItemAnimator(null);
posts_rView.setHasFixedSize(true);

gridPostAdapter=new StarredAdapter(timelineDataList);
posts_rView.setAdapter(gridPostAdapter);
```

Data Updation Code:

```
private  Emitter.Listener handlePosts = new Emitter.Listener(){

    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args){
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray)args[0];
            Needle.onMainThread().execute(() -> {
                timelineDataList.clear();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    try {
                        //JSONArray arr=jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                        JSONObject ob=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        post_username=ob.getString("_pid");
                        post_fullname=ob.getString("owner_fullname");

                        if(ob.has("owner_profPic"))post_profPic=ob.getString("owner_profPic");
                        else post_profPic="";

                        post_time=ob.getString("time");

                        post_link=ob.getString("img_link");
                        likes_counter=ob.getString("likes_counter");
                        comments_counter=ob.getString("comments_counter");
                        if(ob.has("caption")) post_caption=ob.getString("caption");
                        else post_caption=null;

                        //Skipping Private Posts
                        if(ob.getString("private_post_stat").equals("yes")&&!post_username.equals(my_username)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                            private_post_stat = ob.getString("private_post_stat");

                        comment_disabled=ob.getString("comment_disabled");

                        share_disabled=ob.getString("share_disabled");

                        download_disabled=ob.getString("download_disabled");

                        if(ob.has("short_book_content")) short_book_content=ob.getString("short_book_content");
                        else short_book_content=null;
                        society_name_adp=ob.getString("society");

                        addTimelineData(post_username,post_fullname,post_profPic,post_time,post_link,post_caption,
                                private_post_stat,comment_disabled,share_disabled,download_disabled,likes_counter,comments_counter,short_book_content,society_name_adp);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                RecyclerView.Adapter adapter=posts_rView.getAdapter();
                posts_rView.setAdapter(null);
                posts_rView.setAdapter(adapter);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error",e.toString());
        }
    }
};

private void addTimelineData(String username,String fullname,String post_profPic,String time,String img_link,String caption,
                             String private_post_stat,String comment_disabled,String share_disabled,String download_disabled,String likes_counter,
                             String comments_counter,String short_book_content,String society_name_adp){
    boolean isRepeated = false;
    for(TimelineData data:timelineDataList){
        if (data.getTime().equals(time)) {
            isRepeated = true;
        }
    }

    if(!isRepeated){
        timelineDataList.add(new TimelineData(username,fullname,post_profPic,time,img_link,caption,private_post_stat,comment_disabled,share_disabled,download_disabled,likes_counter,comments_counter,short_book_content,society_name_adp));
        gridPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // posts_rView.scrollToPosition(gridPostAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
       // posts_rView.scrollToPosition(0);
    }

     //gridPostAdapter.notifyItemInserted(timelineDataList.size()-1);
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StarViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //loading img
    Glide.with( parent.getContext()).asBitmap().load(arrayList.get(position)).apply(new RequestOptions()
        .override(200, 200)
        .dontAnimate()
        .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#20001919"))))
        .thumbnail(0.1f)
        .into(holder.img);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Why you set recyclerview adapter to null and again set adpter RecyclerView.Adapter adapter=posts_rView.getAdapter();
                posts_rView.setAdapter(null);

Comment: please post item layout also here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not quite understand yet why the flickering and repositioning to the first element is occurring in your case, as I do not see the updating policy of your `RecyclerView`. However, I would like to suggest something which might remove the problem.

1. I would like to suggest you remove the `setInitialPrefetchItemCount` and `setItemPrefetchEnabled` configurations while setting `GridLayoutManager`. This will aid in case of you are having a nested `RecyclerView` which is not your case.
2. You are setting adapter each time you are updating your data from the server. I guess you are calling the update action code when you are scrolling the items. Which you should not. Moreover, please remove setting up the adapter of your `RecyclerView` each time you are updating the dataset. Just use, `notifyDataSetChanged` after each of your updates. Do not clear the `timelineDataList` and append the new items instead, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter.
3. You are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in `addTimelineData` after each insert to your list. This should be done only after adding all the elements to the list.

So I would like to propose the following code for setting your adapter and updating your `RecyclerView`. Please note that I have not tested the code and you might have to modify some errors which might occur.

The code for setting up the layout manager and the adapter.

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(v.getContext(),3);
posts_rView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
posts_rView.setHasFixedSize(true);

gridPostAdapter = new StarredAdapter(timelineDataList);
posts_rView.setAdapter(gridPostAdapter);
```

The code for updating the list.

```
private  Emitter.Listener handlePosts = new Emitter.Listener(){

    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args){
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)args[0];
            Needle.onMainThread().execute(() -> {

                // Do not clear the list. Just append the new data in the list instead
                // timelineDataList.clear();

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    try {
                        JSONObject ob = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        post_username = ob.getString("_pid");
                        post_fullname = ob.getString("owner_fullname");
                        if(ob.has("owner_profPic")) post_profPic = ob.getString("owner_profPic");
                        else post_profPic = "";

                        post_time = ob.getString("time");

                        post_link = ob.getString("img_link");
                        likes_counter = ob.getString("likes_counter");
                        comments_counter = ob.getString("comments_counter");
                        if(ob.has("caption")) post_caption = ob.getString("caption");
                        else post_caption = null;

                        //Skipping Private Posts
                        if(ob.getString("private_post_stat").equals("yes")&&!post_username.equals(my_username)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                            private_post_stat = ob.getString("private_post_stat");

                        comment_disabled = ob.getString("comment_disabled");
                        share_disabled = ob.getString("share_disabled");
                        download_disabled = ob.getString("download_disabled");

                        if (ob.has("short_book_content")) short_book_content = ob.getString("short_book_content");
                        else short_book_content = null;

                        society_name_adp = ob.getString("society");
                        addTimelineData(post_username, post_fullname, post_profPic, post_time, post_link,post_caption, private_post_stat, comment_disabled, share_disabled, download_disabled, likes_counter, comments_counter, short_book_content, society_name_adp);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                gridPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error",e.toString());
        }
    }
};

private void addTimelineData(String username, String fullname, String post_profPic, String time, String img_link, String caption, String private_post_stat, String comment_disabled, String share_disabled, String download_disabled, String likes_counter, String comments_counter, String short_book_content, String society_name_adp) {

    boolean isRepeated = false;
    for(TimelineData data:timelineDataList){
        if (data.getTime().equals(time)) {
            isRepeated = true;
        }
    }

    if(!isRepeated){
        timelineDataList.add(new TimelineData(username,fullname,post_profPic,time,img_link,caption,private_post_stat,comment_disabled,share_disabled,download_disabled,likes_counter,comments_counter,short_book_content,society_name_adp));

        // Do not call notifyDataSetChanged each time you are adding an item. This will be called in the call function above. So remove this line.
        // gridPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Try to add some pagination in the server side API if it is not there already so that you might fetch the next 20 dataset instead of fetching the whole data again when you are scrolling down.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sir thanks a lot for your great enlightenment but could you please tell how to do pagination in server side api for fectching next 20 dataset

Comment: Glad to know that I could help. Yes, about pagination, this is a whole other discussion. However, I am just giving you a heads-up. Try sending an extra parameter page number for example 1 from the client side so that the server understands, it needs to send the first 20 data. For fetching the next 20, send page number 2 from the client and so on...

Comment: Thanks again for your great help

Comment: @ReazMurshed I'm kind of having the same problem, and as you said I've nested recyclerview of images and it flickers a lot, So I've tried with removing the image recyclerview but same happens, I'm using reverse layout for recyclerview, do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Setting up the RecylerView with reverse layout should not be a problem actually. Without seeing the code, it is difficult to understand your problem though. If you have posted a question somewhere, please post the link here - i will try to take a look!

Comment: I guess I've found the issue it was related to LinearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd flag, I changed to it to true, seems like It's working now, Thank you. If I get this issue again, I'll let you know, thanks again :)

Comment: Sure thing! Glad to know that you could solve the problem!